# Bottom Navigation View gets Shrink Down

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview, bottomnavigationview

I have made an app with bottom navigation view with Promo, Store, Reward, Coupon and Account tabs when I am changing from Coupon fragment to any other fragment, the bottom navigation view gets shrunk down as shown in the image, I tried changing layout width, height and converting coordinator layout to linear layout but it didn't help. The problem is occurring when I'm switching from home to any other tab only.

Layout File activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    android:text="@string/title_home"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/selector_bottom_navigation"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/selector_bottom_navigation"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Java File MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //loading the default fragment
    loadFragment(new PromoFragment());

    //getting bottom navigation view and attaching the listener
    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    BottomNavigationViewUtils.disableShiftMode(navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreatePanelMenu(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_wallet, menu);
    return super.onCreatePanelMenu(featureId, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_wallet1:
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_qrcode:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScannerActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.navigation_promo:
            fragment = new PromoFragment();
            break;

        case R.id.navigation_store:
            fragment = new StoreFragment();
            break;

        case R.id.navigation_reward:
            fragment = new RewardFragment();
            break;

        case R.id.navigation_coupon:
            fragment = new CouponFragment();
            break;

        case R.id.navigation_account:
            fragment = new AccountFragment();
            break;
    }

    return loadFragment(fragment);
}

private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is the picture I meant:

[image]

I previously added `SearchView` to the coupon fragment and fragment store

Comment: I tried making your statements clearer, but the last sentence really stumped me: "When I click on bugs like going down, but when I click on the fragment store and coupon to be normal again, this is a navigation drawer that I made." what does this mean?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue but in my case instead of view, the size of the labels get shrunk. I tried removing "android:fitsSystemWindows" attribute but it didn't help. Any solution ? My bottomnavigationview is in Constraintlayout.

Comment: you can try with change all off your fragment layout with coordinator layout, it's work fine for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that if you are using a coordinator layout and viewpager inside a fragment, you will notice that the viewpager extends the screen a bit. Just disable the scroll features of the coordinator layout inside the fragment and you will notice the bottom bar doesn't get shrunk. Weird I know, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

I add android:fitsSystemWindows="false" in CoordinatorLayout and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Find `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your fragment xml and remove this line
or change it to `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`. Your problem will be solved.