# BottomNavigationBar goes down partially when I change fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

I use BottomNavigationBar(bnb) with Navigation(android jetpack). It's a single-activity app. There are 3 fragments. One of them is starting. When I perform the navigation from starting fragment to any outher, bnb goes down for half of it hight. When I go back or perform navigation between not starting fragments everything is ok.

[image: as shown here]

**Activity**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemIconSize="@dimen/bnb_icon_size"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
        app:elevation="@dimen/margin_small"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation_view"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**one of the fragments**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="callback"
           type="(...)ui.info.InfoFragmentCallback" />

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/set_coord_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_email"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteOverlayTransparency45"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_contact_us_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/title_contact_us"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteOverlayTransparency45"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/info_email"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_version"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_large"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_version"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteOverlayTransparency45"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/info_email"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_app_rate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/title_rate_app"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteOverlayTransparency45"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/info_google_badge"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/info_google_badge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size_large"
            android:elevation="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:onClick="@{(view)->callback.onAppRateClicked()}"
            android:src="@drawable/google_play_badge"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/info_privacy_policy"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/info_email"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_privacy_policy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_huge"
            android:onClick="@{(view)->callback.onPrivacyClicked()}"
            android:text="@string/privacy_policy_title"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    private NavController mNavController;

    private final BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener mOnNavigationItemReselectedListener = item -> {
        /*multiple touches may must nothing*/
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, mNavController);

        initBottomNavigationMenu();
    }

    private void initBottomNavigationMenu() {
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(mOnNavigationItemReselectedListener);
    }

    public void performNavigation(int navId) {
        mNavController.navigate(navId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(null);
    }
}
```

**bnb menu**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/starting_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_image"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/favorites_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_star"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/info_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Where can be a problem?

Comment: I had similar problem few months ago, this answer helped me.
[Bottom navigation view gets shrink down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53552216/bottom-navigation-view-gets-shrink-down)